# Why does WPF define it's own type to represent points in 2d space instead of using System.Numerics.Vector2

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, simd

I recently learned that C# has types like [`Vector2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector2?view=netframework-4.8) and `Vector3` that are desinged to use SIMD instructions if possible.

So the type `Vector2` is perfect to represent a point in a 2d-space like the screen. However why is it that WPF and UWP does not use this type for their representations of 2d-points [`System.Windows.Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.point?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Windows.Foundation.Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/windows.foundation.point?view=dotnet-uwp-10.0).

Comment: I would assume, because a vector and a point are semantically different. A vector roughly denotes a direction, and a point is a point.

Comment: @ckuri: The core of your comment (conceptual differences) in response to the question is correct, but vectors denote direction **and magnitude** (i.e. what you'd call the length of the vector). A **normalized** vector denotes only direction (as a normalized vector's magnitude is by definition equal to 1)

Comment: Vector2 is single precision and available starting in .NET 4.6.  Changing WPF from double to single and Point to Vector2 would probably break a lot of code...

Answer (score 2):

Just because two classes happen to have the same properties does not automatically mean that they should be merged into a single shared class.

For example, a lat/lon pair and a (2D) point can both be represented by two decimal values; but they are conceptually different. A point is located on a 2D flat plane whereas a lat/lon pair is located on a sphere's surface (which is a 2D surface but curved, it's not a flat plane).
Because these are two distinct concepts with a distinct context, we keep these two separate because there is nothing to gain from thinking of them as being the same type of data.

**Conceptually, a vector is very different from a point.** However, practically, a vector's data can be represented by a single point because the other point is (by convention) assumed to be (0,0) or (0,0,0).

Technically speaking, a vector should be represented by two points, as the vector denotes the *difference* between these points. A vector from (2,2) to (3,3) is the same as the vector from (100,4) to (101,5) and also the same as the vector from (0,0) to (1,1). All three vectors denote a (+1,+1) difference between two points.

However, as we are only interested in the difference between two points and not not actually care about the two points themselves, we can cut down on the amount of data we need to store by using the convention that the first point is always the origin point (0,0), which allows us to retain all necessary information (the difference between the origin point and the second point) but requires us to store less variable data. That's a net positive and therefore there is no reason not to do it.

---

This is an argument of **readability over brevity**. There is no significant cost to keeping two conceptual entities separated, but there is a massive increase in readability by doing so.
If you were to merge them, you'd get no real benefit, but you would significantly reduce readability by destroying the separation between these two unrelated entities.

The source of your suggestion is an (absolutely human) tendency to overapply paradigms, in this case DRY. While there is value in reevaluating things to see if you can optimize (or unduplicate) things; you can also go overboard and look for patterns that aren't really there. The suggestion to merge vectors and points is overboard, but the origin of your suggestion does come from trying to apply good practice.